# Android ADB LogCat: ANDROID_PRINTF_LOG environment variable not working

Tags: android, adb, logcat

When I execute `adb logcat --help`, the Logcat usage details are printed. Near the bottom, it describes two environment variables:

> "If not specified on the commandline, filterspec is set from
>   **ANDROID_LOG_TAGS**. If no filterspec is found, filter defaults to '*:I'
>
> If not specified with -v, format is set from **ANDROID_PRINTF_LOG** or
>   defaults to 'brief'"

On my Windows 7 machine, when I add **ANDROID_LOG_TAGS** to my environment variables with a value of "Foo:* *:S", for example, then it works!  Calling `adb logcat` without tag filters will default to my custom values.  Great!

However, when I add **ANDROID_PRINTF_LOG**, with any valid setting (I prefer "time"), this will NOT have an affect on the logcat output.  `adb logcat` still outputs in "brief" format.

Is there some mistake I am making, or something I can do to get to work??
I would really like to get this working because I use "-v time" a lot.

My ADB version is 1.0.31.

Thanks in advance.

Android pages themselves didn't mention this variable:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html 
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#outputFormat

Comment: Are you sure you haven't run out of environment space?  If you use the command line a lot, you might be much happier with a *nix platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ANDROID_PRINTF_LOG** and **ANDROID_LOG_TAGS** are processed by the `logcat` binary running on the device side. It means that in order to affect the output format the variables need to be set inside of the device's shell environment. And you are setting them in your PC's shell environment. The reason why **ANDROID_LOG_TAGS** still works when set on the PC side is the following:

When you run the `adb logcat` the actual command being executed is this:

```
adb shell export ANDROID_LOG_TAGS=\"%ANDROID_LOG_TAGS%\"; exec logcat
```

i.e. your local **ANDROID_LOG_TAGS** value is being copied into the device's environment before every `logcat` call. Not sure if not copying the **ANDROID_PRINTF_LOG** as well qualifies as a bug though. `adb -h` lists all the variables supported on the PC side and **ANDROID_PRINTF_LOG** is not among them.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!  Are there any workarounds where you could slip in your ANDROID_PRINTF_LOG preference as well (besides typing the "-v <format>" every time), like an alias or something?

Comment: on rooted device you can add settting and export of `ANDROID_PRINTF_LOG` variable to `/system/etc/mkshrc`